# Recharts import fail

Tags: reactjs, recharts

When I use recharts with react

```
import {LineChart, Line, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, Legend} from 'recharts';
```

and then 
"npm run-script build"
I got this error

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Failed to minify the code from this file:

        ./node_modules/d3-array/src/count.js:2
```

Anyone can help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've stuck with the same problem, any luck finding solution to this?

Comment: update "d3-array": "^1.2.2",
"d3-scale": "^2.2.0",  in package.json. It works for me.